# How much does a taxi from London to Dover cost?

Tags: uk, airport-transfer, taxis

I need to know how much costs a taxi from London to Dover. I found a website http://www.dover-taxi.com/taxi-dover-london/ and the price is 124 GBP. ... Is this price correct?

Comment: I would say yes. The price is quoted on the website. Do you think that they would quote wrong prices?

Comment: Why do you want to take a taxi? Unless there's loads of you, a train is likely to be cheaper, and possibly quicker too

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  That's the price, as indicated on a commercial website. Of course, other companies may be more expensive, and it depends where in London you're travelling from - remember, London is big!

[A pdf of prices is available](http://www.channelswimmingassociation.com/images/documents/travel_advice.pdf) and it's worth noting they also mention private taxi for about 125 GBP.  However, note that it's just certain companies - DO NOT hop in a Black taxi (the famous London type) and expect to pay this - you'll end up paying up to 3 times that amount!

Best bet - ring the company up, make a booking, and confirm the price.

(possibly better bet - take a National Express bus - they're comfortable, cheap, and may even have wifi - plus you get a better view)